# Combine two arrays as one based on same key and values

Tags: php, json

I am facing trouble in combining the following array into one array. It would be really helpful if any guidance or code snippet were offered.

I have this array:

```
[{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Flash Point\/Fire Point","key":"tests"}]
[{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Flash Point\/Fire Point","key":"tests"},{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Softening Point","key":"tests"}]
```

This is the result I want:

```
[{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Flash Point\/Fire Point","key":"tests"},{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Softening Point","key":"tests"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the original JSON data contains arrays of objects there is no PHP function that will perform the merge. Here's a PHP coded solution that will work for simple objects:

```
<?php
function searchObjects($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $value) {
     if ($value == $needle) {  //Object comparison works for simple objects
        return true;
    }
}
    return false;
}

$array1 = json_decode('[{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Flash Point\/Fire Point","key":"tests"}]');

$array2 = json_decode('[{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Flash Point\/Fire Point","key":"tests"}, 
       {"id":"RMU-442","test":"Softening Point","key":"tests"}]');

foreach ($array2 as $value){
  if (!searchObjects($value, $array1)) {
        $array1[] = $value;
  }
}

$result = json_encode($array1);
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

include jQuery and use following code

```
 var v = [{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Flash Point\/Fire Point","key":"tests"}];
 var v1 = [{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Flash Point\/Fire Point","key":"tests"}, 
           {"id":"RMU-442","test":"Softening Point","key":"tests"}];
 var v3= jQuery.merge(v,v1);
 console.log(v3);
```

[see jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/siddhapura/XVX5Z/)

Comment: His question is tagged as PHP so I assume he is expecting a PHP answer otherwise it would be tagged with JavaScript or JQuery.

Comment: The original question is tagged with PHP and JSON. Including jQuery is not possible in a PHP environment.

Comment: @Prix, I know it was posted into php and json tag. but i thought he missed tag, because the statement [{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Flash Point\/Fire Point","key":"tests"}] is not possible into php. Mike is that possible into PHP?

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura he can use [**json_decode**](https://eval.in/37377) to read it and array functions to merge so yes it is, also it was tagged only with PHP the JSON tag was added by me because his information is about JSON. [**Sample**](https://eval.in/37377)

Comment: PHP will handle JSON data, but there's no array function that will merge arrays of objects. I've added a solution coded in PHP that does what is required.